# ¿Cómo cambiar el tiempo del SetInterval de acuerdo a una condición?

Tags: javascript, condiciones, setinterval

He hecho un juego donde cada vez que le doy a una imagen que aparece en la pantalla me suma un punto. Lo que estoy intentando es que al llegar a 10 puntos la frecuencia con la que me salen las imágenes sea más corta, es decir, que vayan cambiando más rápido.

Esta sería la función donde estoy intentando que pase:

```
function automatic(){
    setInterval(random,4000);

    if( "puntuacion" >= 10){
       setInterval (random,2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: de donde obtienes la variable puntuacion???

Comment: Tengo una función tal que así: function clicktopo(){


  document.getElementById("puntuacion").innerHTML = c++;

}  De ahí cada clic que le doy a la imágen me suma un punto

Comment: ok, pero lo que tienes en tu condicion if("puntuacion"){} no es una variable verdad? que es? pare que intentas poner el id

Comment: si, es un id. pero igualmente he intentado hacerlo con una variable y sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Te sale algún error?

Comment: No, simplemente no me funciona

Comment: puedes colocar el código completo?

Comment: Tienes que guardar el estado del setInterval en una variable para poder después interactuar con ella: var tiempo = setInterval(random,4000); luego ya puedes hacer tiempo = setInterval(random,2000);

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacer una función que sea sumar puntos y otra para cambiar el intervalo, usando `clearInterval()`. Por ejemplo:

```js
var puntos = 0;
var miIntervalo;

// Recibo un valor para sumar a la puntuación
function puntuacion(nuevos_puntos) {
  puntos += nuevos_puntos;
  
  if (puntos >= 10) {
    cambiarIntervalo(2000);
  }
}

// función para cambiar el intervalo
function cambiarIntervalo(milisegundos) {
  clearInterval(miIntervalo);
  miIntervalo = setInterval(random, milisegundos);
}

// Cree esta función para mostrar un texto pero acá debería
// ir lo que vas a ejecutar
function random() {
  console.log("puntuación:", puntos);
}

// inicializo el intervalo en 4000
cambiarIntervalo(4000);
```

```html
<!-- suma un punto cada vez que se hace clic -->
<button onclick="javascript:puntuacion(1)">Sumar puntos</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Debería existir un `counter` que almacene los clicks dados Dentro de un ciclo, una vez superado ese ciclo deberías crear un nuevo `setInterval|` con un tiempo menor al qué ocurre antes de superar el límite de clicks.

```
function intervalos() {
    let counter = 0
    while(counter<= 10) {
        window.setInterval(function, tiempo1);
    }
    window.setInterval(function, tiempo2);
 }
```

Luego invocar a la función

```
 intervalos()
```

Aclarando que está respuesta busca aportar en código una propuesta de cómo hacerse pero que claramente puede mejorarse y completarse

Answer (score 0):

Si el segundo parámetro del [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) se lo asignas dependiendo de la condición lograrás lo que deseas:

> Crearé una función que acepta como primer parámetro un callback y como segundo una puntuación para que puedas ver el resultado:

```js
function automatic (puntuacion, callback) {
  setInterval(callback, puntuacion >= 10 && 2000 || 4000);
}

automatic(1, () => console.log('puntuacion 1'));
automatic(100, () => console.log('puntuacion 100'));
```

Es bueno aclarar que cada vez que llames a esta función, crearás un nuevo `setInterval` (el anterior se seguirá ejecutando como puedes notar en el snippet anterior), por lo que lo mejor es eliminar la referencia anterior antes de crear una nueva:

```
var intervalo;

function automatic (puntuacion, callback) {
  clearInterval(intervalo);
  intervalo = setInterval(callback, puntuacion >= 10 && 2000 || 4000);
}
```